# WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'

Tags: xcode, warnings, target

My Xcode version is 5.1.1. when I analyze (command + B) project, but having follow warning.

> WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking
>   two modules of different target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking two modules of different
>   target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'
>   WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking
>   two modules of different target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking two modules of different
>   target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'
>   WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking
>   two modules of different target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking two modules of different
>   target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'
>   WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking
>   two modules of different target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking two modules of different
>   target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'
>   WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking
>   two modules of different target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0' WARNING: Linking two modules of different
>   target triples: 'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'
>   WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'
>
> (null): Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   'thumbv7-apple-ios3.1.3' and 'thumbv7-apple-ios4.2.0'

Comment: It looks like some of the libraries you are using need to be re-compiled.  There is not enough information to answer this question properly, however.

Comment: I Release-iphoneos library and Release-iphonesimulator library merger

Comment: I've no idea what you are talking about.